# Today's date format - Day (Shorthand) Date Number Month (Shorthand) - PHP

Tags: php, date, date-format

I have a feed which gives feed in the following format: "Fri 14 Oct"

I want to see if today's date matches the date from the feed. My problem is the format of today's date/

```
  $today = date("d m");
```

This outputs 17 10.

What is the best way to format $today so that it outputs Day (shorthand) space date (number) Month (shorthand) ?

Comment: You should specify what happens for dates between 1-9, is it 01 or 1 for the first of the month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about:

```
$today = date("D j M");
```

As explained in [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) reference manual.

Anyway you should be aware of timezone issues unless you are 100% sure that your server is in the same timezone of the feed you are comparing.

I would follow a different approach though, you can **parse** the feed's date using [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) which also understand timezones, and then compare it with today's date.

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = date("D d M");
```

[PHP Date Documentation](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)

Comment: OP didn't specify what happens with dates 1-9 but I would expect it without leading zero since it's probably supposed to be human-readable. I usually don't read Fri 09 Oct but Fri 9 Oct

Comment: Oh sure, should be $today = date("D j M");

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
// Prints the day
echo date("l") . "<br>";

// Prints the day, date, month, year, time, AM or PM
echo date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A");
?>
```

For more details, please visit http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp

Comment: To whoever gave me a -1!  I am not a PHP guy...  Nevertheless, a simple Google search for "PHP Date" gave me this result.  If you actually read that page/link I posted above, you will learn how to do it yourself.  I just did not spoon feed the answer you expected.  This is in keeping with the philosophy "It is more worthwhile to teach someone to do something than to do it for them."

Comment: I gave you the -1, you did not answer the asker question, so just don't post any answer at all. I posted a correct answer AND gave him the link for further reading, you totally deserved it.